# Views without paths

Tags: views, panels

I have a panel with a main content area and a sidebar, path is "news".

Now, I want to create a view to be shown in the main content area, that lists a certain content-type. That's easy enough, but how do you make it so that view doesn't get its own path? I only want the view to be accessible through that panel page.

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a block, as opposed to a page, and display the block in the panel.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still quite new, so the terminilogy is a bit confusing sometimes.

Comment: If he's using Panels, he should _not_ create a block. Blocks are very limited, and should be replaced with Content Panes, when used within Panels.

Comment: Unless I find out in a second they cannot be themed, they seem to do all I need :-) In which sense are they limited?

Comment: I would like to embed views page displays in my own callbacks, but without having to assign paths to them (the views are never displayed in their own page, but currently they are  'pages' and not 'blocks'). Is that possible?